# Octave: defining a function to interpolate data points

Tags: function, unix, octave

> 1. Write an octave function to implement `f(x) = sin(3x)/(0.4+(x-2)^2)`.
> 2. Write an octave script to interpolate between the values of `f(x) = sin(3x)/(0.4+(x-2)^2)` sampled uniformly at up to 9 points in the interval `x = [0,4]`.

I'm confused as to what this question is asking. I interpreted the 1st part as defining a function `fx` that can be called from anywhere to return the values of `f(x)` for a given `x`, but I'm not sure if the `x`'s have to be inputs.

For the 2nd part, am I correct in using the `interpl` function?

**My attempt:**

Function file *fx.m*

```
function fx

x=(0:0.25:4);

y = sin(3*x)/(0.4+(x-2))^2

endfunction
```

But this only returns 1 value for `y`. I need to return 9 uniformly spaced samples. I feel as though I need to use a `for` loop somehow...

Script *intpl.m*

```
1;

yi=interpl(x,y,0.4:0.4:3.6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your teacher wants something like:

```
function y = f(x)
  y = ....x..... (fill your formula here but use elementwise operations [1])
endfunction
```

and then use this function for the given range:

```
x = linspace (0, 4, 9);
y = f(x)
```

if you want to have this in one file foo.m be sure to not start the file with the function definition. I normally use "1;" so your script foo.m becomes:

```
1;
function y = f(x)
    x = ....;
endfunction

x = linspace (...);
y = f(x)
plot (x, y) # if you want to plot it
```

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html